# Launch a batch from a web page

Tags: html, batch-file

I have a program that I am designing in HTML/PHP where I then use a compiler that puts all of it into a .exe (if you know of a better method, I am open to suggestions, but I only know so many languages).

I am wanting to know how I can program the page to open/run a local batch file. I know this is a big security risk and I know a lot of languages don't "allow" this, but this is an internal program that's going to be used in house that calls local scripts to do various different things. I have tried the typical onclick="process.start/Shell (/folder/file.bat), but that and the basic (a href) don't do anything.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you used the correct path to your batch file? PHP tends to execute relative to whatever script root is specified, and if that's not present, it can miss obvious things. Also, could you please give us a sample of your code?

Comment: Pretty sure I'm using the correct path, and the scripts the page is referencing are there. 

The samples of the codes I've tried are included in my original post.